# Is there a way to transfer many photos from iPhone to Mac without losing filters & edits?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, photos, lightning

Is there an way to get the photos off my iPhone **without losing the filters and edits that I have used?**

**I just want the jpeg files**, I don't want to sync the phone to a database like iPhoto or (now) Photos.

I don't want to use iPhotos because it keeps all the photostreams on my MB Air and uses up disk space. I suppose I could use it with photostreams disabled.

If I use AirPlay, it takes *forever* and chokes when I want to do a few hundred at a time.

**Is there a way to do it with the iPhone connected by cable?**

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found is with the new **Photos app**.

In Photos, go to the **Import tab**, then **select the photos** you want to import.

This will create a **new album** with the date of the import.

In the new album, press:

```
cmd-A to select all
cmd-shift-E to export
> choose options
export
cmd-backspace to delete all
```

note: **do NOT choose a subfolder name** unless you want every single day to have its own folder.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/nst/filters:

> 1. import the photos with Image Capture
> 2. run `$ python filters.py`

The script will read the .AAE files which store the effect and apply the effect to the matching .JPG image.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. Suggestion: add info about the extra args such as --overwrite, probably the most useful one.