# Is it possible to import iPhone photos with corresponding .AAE files to Photos on the Mac?

Tags: iphone, photos

I'm transitioning to using Photos.app on both iOS and OS X - with the intention to use *iCloud Photo Library*...

Before making this change I had to move a bunch of photos off an iPhone to free up space. I did so using *Image Capture* on the Mac - and I've ended up with `.JPG`s paired with `.AAE`s (the latter, as I understand it, containing the image edits).

(So, I moved the photos off the iPhone to a folder on a Mac, duplicated on external disk, did a back up, then deleted the images on the iPhone)

I've read [this Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175988/is-there-a-way-to-transfer-many-photos-from-iphone-to-mac-without-losing-filters) with tells of a method to use a python script to apply of the filters to the corresponding images.

What I'd like to know: is it possible to import both the `.JPG` files and `.AAE` files so that the original image is still available in Photos? E.g. so that the *revert* option would still be available...

Answer (score 1):

best way to do this is via AirDrop, its super fast and doesn't require a internet connection (bluetooth and WIFI need to be switched on though). Works with iPhone5 or up, maybe 4S as well but i didn't try.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201463